# Drupal Commerce - Permissions > Roles

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I'm playing around with Drupal Commerce at the moment but can't find `Roles` in Administration > People > Permissions.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Any suggestions?

==== UPDATE

For the record, this is what I see - no sign of a Roles button, tab or link:

[image]

Comment: Maintainer of CK2. What theme did you change to? And you're also using default theme for admin, try changing to "Shiny". That appears to be what's making the overlay get goofy

Comment: This is literally CK out of the box. Checking - it's `Commerce Kickstart Theme 7.x-2.32 (default theme)`. Changing to `Shiny` fixed the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Guess I have a bug to check out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Roles" page is link as a local task from the permissions page.

[image]

Here is a link to the official community documentation, as well, https://www.drupal.org/node/120614.

Comment: I don't see a Roles link. See the screenshot.